# Storing data in HttpRequest object for life of page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, memory-management, webforms, httprequest

I'm trying to see if it's possible to store an object in the HttpRequest that I can grab throughout the pages loading lifecycle.

On a category grid, I am displaying many different products. Each product has the ability to be added to a WishList.  I have a custom control for the WishList that generates a dropdown list of the users current WishLists.  If I have 20 products, this control will get hit 20 times and attempt to load the object from my datalayer that many times.  I've been using Session and have tried HttpContext.Cache, but from my understanding those will persist for X amount of minutes.

So I'm wondering is there a way to use the HttpRequest object to store my List(Of WishList) and that way I can just grab it every other time my custom control is hit.

Thanks

Edit: To add some code, this is how I'd like to set up my Property in my custom control (or up for better recommendations)

```
Public Property WishLists As Collection(Of Catalog.WishList)
        Get
            If _wishLists Is Nothing Then

                If Me.Page.Request.SomeMethod("MyCustomObject") IsNot Nothing Then
                    _wishLists = TryCast(Me.Page.Request.SomeMethod("MyCustomObject"), List(Of Catalog.WishList))
                Else
                    _wishLists = Catalog.WishList.FindByUserId(SessionManager.GetCurrentUserId())
                    Me.Page.Request.SomeMethod("MyCustomObject") = _wishLists
                End If

            End If
            Return _wishLists
        End Get
        Set(value As Collection(Of Catalog.WishList))
            _wishLists = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: I think you would be better off using session.  Yes session has an expiration, but each time the user interacts with your site the session expiration will be extended.  I don't believe you could use the request object as this would be disposed at the end of the page life-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that very easy.

Put this code accessible from project (check my other asp.net answers how)  and use this methods to manage entire user tasks.

**Based on asp.net id of session** I go to create a collection of objects from each user on that specific session.
If user go left and right around your pages of your website the value of those variables doesn’t change.
*If your user go back from your site you need to use another approach (client side, like cookie or  IndexedDB)*

The code:

```
Private ObjsParams As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
Private ObjsVariables As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

Friend Sub Init()

    If AspNetId IsNot Nothing Then
        If ObjsParams Is Nothing Then ObjsParams = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        If ObjsVariables Is Nothing Then ObjsVariables = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    End If

End Sub

Function GetAppContext() As HttpContextBase

    If HttpContext.Current IsNot Nothing AndAlso
        HttpContext.Current.Request IsNot Nothing AndAlso
        HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext IsNot Nothing AndAlso
        HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext IsNot Nothing Then

        Return HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext

    End If

    If HttpContext.Current IsNot Nothing Then
        Return New HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)
    End If

    Return Nothing

End Function

Friend ReadOnly Property AspNetId As String
    Get

        Dim CtxBase As HttpContextBase = GetAppContext().Request.RequestContext.HttpContext

        Try
            Dim getSessionId As Func(Of String) = Function()

                                                      Dim mSessionID As String = ""



                                                      If CtxBase IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                                                      CtxBase.Request IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                                                      CtxBase.Request.Cookies IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                                                      CtxBase.Request.Cookies.Count > 0 AndAlso
                                                      CtxBase.Request.Cookies.Item("ASP.NET_SessionId") IsNot Nothing Then
                                                          mSessionID = CtxBase.Request.Cookies.Item("ASP.NET_SessionId").Value
                                                      End If



                                                      If Len(mSessionID) = 0 Then
                                                          If CtxBase IsNot Nothing AndAlso CtxBase.Session IsNot Nothing Then
                                                              If CtxBase.Session("SessionID") IsNot Nothing Then
                                                                  mSessionID = CStr(CtxBase.Session("SessionID"))
                                                              End If
                                                          End If
                                                      End If


                                                      If Len(mSessionID) = 0 Then

                                                          If CtxBase IsNot Nothing AndAlso CtxBase.Session IsNot Nothing Then
                                                              If CtxBase.Session.SessionID IsNot Nothing Then
                                                                  mSessionID = CtxBase.Session.SessionID
                                                              End If
                                                          End If

                                                      End If


                                                      If Len(mSessionID) = 0 Then
                                                          If CtxBase IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                                                             CtxBase.Request IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                                                             CtxBase.Request.Params IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                                                             CtxBase.Request.Params.HasKeys Then

                                                              mSessionID = CtxBase.Request.Params("ASP.NET_SessionId")

                                                          End If
                                                      End If

                                                      Return mSessionID

                                                  End Function


            Return getSessionId()

        Catch ex As Exception

            ' Here is comming if you use async methods 
            If CtxBase IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                CtxBase.Request IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                CtxBase.Request.Params IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                CtxBase.Request.Params.HasKeys Then

                Dim CERT_COOKIE As String = CtxBase.Request.Params("HTTP_COOKIE")

                If Len(CERT_COOKIE) > 0 Then
                    Return CERT_COOKIE
                End If

            End If

            ' desperate
            Return Nothing

        End Try

    End Get

End Property


Friend Function GetObj(chiave As String) As Object
    Dim res As Object = Nothing
    If ObjsVariables IsNot Nothing AndAlso AspNetId IsNot Nothing Then
        If ObjsVariables.ContainsKey(AspNetId & "~" & chiave) Then
            res = ObjsVariables(AspNetId & "~" & chiave)
        End If
    End If
    Return res
End Function


Friend Sub SetObj(chiave As String, valore As Object)
    If ObjsVariables IsNot Nothing AndAlso AspNetId IsNot Nothing Then
        If Not ObjsVariables.ContainsKey(AspNetId & "~" & chiave) Then
            ObjsVariables.Add(AspNetId & "~" & chiave, valore)
        Else
            ObjsVariables(AspNetId & "~" & chiave) = valore
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function GetParams(chiave As String) As Object
    Dim res As Object = Nothing
    Try
        If ObjsParams IsNot Nothing AndAlso AspNetId IsNot Nothing Then
            If ObjsParams.ContainsKey(AspNetId & "~" & chiave) Then
                res = ObjsParams(AspNetId & "~" & chiave)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Log here 
    End Try

    Return res
End Function

Sub SetParams(chiave As String, valore As Object)
    Try
        If ObjsParams IsNot Nothing AndAlso AspNetId IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not ObjsParams.ContainsKey(AspNetId & "~" & chiave) Then
                ObjsParams.Add(AspNetId & "~" & chiave, valore)
            Else
                ObjsParams(AspNetId & "~" & chiave) = valore
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Log here
    End Try
End Sub
```

Usage:
Create a global asax file and in session start event init session variables

```
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Try
              Init()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ‘Log here
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then create an infinity of properties by string identification

```
  ‘Your wishList
    Public Property WishList As List(Of Catalog.WishList)
        Get
            Return CType(GetParams("WishList"), List(Of Catalog.WishList))
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Catalog.WishList))
            SetParams("WishList", value)
        End Set
    End Property


    ‘Other property 
    Public Property OtherProperty As String
        Get
            Return CType(GetParams("OtherProperty"), String)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SetParams("OtherProperty", value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

Then until your user is in your site  WishList preserve her value 
Adding:

```
WishList.Add(New Catalog.WishList From {"Alfa ", "Beta", "Zeta"})
```

Getting:

```
 For Each mCat In WishList
        'Print WishList here
 Next
```

Comment: Interesting.  Will give it a play.